# DOM Javascript : can't find input in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm creating a PHP/Javascript, i create a form, with a button who create new input onclick (it work, i can find with elements with the Google Chrome element inspector and i can get the value with a $('').val() ).

The problem is, when i submit my form, i can't see the new input in the '$Post' array.

How to fix this problem?

My function for create new input

```
function newInput(){
var pere = document.getElementById('Inputs_Contener');
var newInput = document.createElement('div');   
var InputName2;
var divToCopy = "#divToCopy";
var idNewInput = "";
var nameNewInput = "";
var nameNewInputSelector = "";
var nameNominalDiameterID = "#Nominal_Diameter_SelectList_1";


InputNumer = InputNumer + 1;
nameNewInput = "Input " + InputNumer;
idNewInput = "Input" + InputNumer + "_Contener"

newInput.setAttribute("id",idNewInput);
pere.appendChild(newInput);

$(divToCopy).clone().appendTo(newInput);

nameNewInputSelector = "#" + idNewInput;
$(nameNewInputSelector).find('#Input_Name').html(nameNewInput);

newNameNominalDiameterID = newNameNominalDiameterID + InputNumer;

$(nameNewInputSelector).find(nameNominalDiameterID).attr("name",newNameNominalDiameterID);
$(nameNewInputSelector).find(nameNominalDiameterID).attr("id",newNameNominalDiameterID);
```

Part of HTML :

```
<form role="form" name="meter_form" action="test2.php" method="post"><div id="Profiles_Contener">
<div id="Profile1_Contener">
    <div id="divToCopy">
        <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" name="Nominal_Diameter_SelectList_1" id="Nominal_Diameter_SelectList_1" id="Nominal_Diameter_SelectList_1">
                    <option>10</option>
                    <option>20</option>
                    <option>30</option>
                </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How I submit :

```
meter_form.submit();
```

Var_dump($Post) result :

http://hpics.li/4e8ce3d

Comment: Please provide the HTML code for the form, as well as the PHP code you're using to handle the form input.

Comment: It looks like the problem is with the submitting; could you show how you submit? By the way,  newInput() looks way too complicated; a few lines should do.  When half the time you use jQuery, and sometimes document.getElementById ...

Comment: I don't see that you're select is within form tags. As was mentioned, more of your code will help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
The real problem is that input created in JS exists, i'm able to see it visualy, in html and i can acces to input values with "alert()" before submitting. But WHEN I SUBMIT my form, it looks like created inputs never exist because they don't appear in the $Post array
$Post array contain only inputs created in HTML

Answer (score 0):

FIXED :

The problem was the  in my HTML, not well placed.

I deplace the form tag in a div above and it fix the problem